# How to `rm` files in current directory and directories inside current directory

Tags: linux, rm

I would like to `rm`  all files that end in `~` in both my current directory and all directories inside my current directory.  I was under the impression that the flag `-r` or `-R` would do this; however, the following commands only remove files ending in `~` in my current directory and not the other directories inside my current directory:

```
rm *~ -r
rm *~ -R
```

Is it even possible to get `rm` to perform as I want it to as explained here and, if so, how?

I use tcsh.

Comment: FYI, what you're trying doesn't work because `rm` doesn't expand patterns like `*~` to lists of filenames itself; the shell is responsible for doing that before `rm` is ever started. For that reason, arguments to rm like `-r` can't change how that process works.

Comment: ...as another aside, options (like `-r`) should go *before* positional arguments (like the filenames given here). Some tools support doing it the other way around, and others don't; assuming that no more option parsing is done after the first positional argument is the safe and compatible approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compatible approach is to tell `find` to construct a file list and pass it to `rm`. Using the newish (added to POSIX around 2005, if memory serves) `-exec ... {} +` syntax will make this both efficient and safe:

```
find . -name '*~' -exec rm -f {} +
```

For newer (4.x) bash, or most releases of zsh, you can also tell the shell to do recursive globbing itself:

```
shopt -s globstar # enable recursive globbing with ** on bash
rm -f **/*~
```

Comment: Don't you need a slash at the end of `find`?

Comment: @staticx, ...perhaps you're thinking of `{} \;`? I'm using `+`, not `;`, and it's specifically the semicolon character which requires escaping. (More pertinantly, the semicolon character also selects a less-efficient mode of operation, invoking `rm` once per file found).

Comment: Yes, that is what I am thinking about.. sorry.

Comment: Interesting, I just read in the man pages about the differences. I guess old habits die hard. It also looks like `-execdir` is the more secure way to run the `exec` command.

Comment: @staticx, `-execdir` is a GNU extension, not a POSIX-standardized option.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it matters if you are running GNU/Linux (I might be wrongly assuming that most people do)

Comment: @staticx, indeed, that's not a fair assumption. Lots of folks on MacOS or a BSD, and the commercial UNIX implementations *do* still exist.

Comment: Weird, my mac mini supprts it oh well

Comment: @staticx, ...which is true because Apple picked up the feature in recent releases. Still, they aren't using GNU's find but their own, so it's not safe to assume feature parity without checking on a feature-by-feature basis.

Comment: Hmm ok, who would know..I had no clue.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all files from every directory using below command:

```
find -name "*~" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

where **find -name "*~"** finds every file which is having name with "~" at last position, **-print0** list down all of file in one line, **xargs -0 rm** which takes list of all file in input and works as rm . And if you want to even delete every directory which is having name with "~" at the end then also you can do it by replacing rm with rm -rf.

Comment: This works fine, but has no advantages over the `-exec rm {} +` approach other than compatibility with older `find` implementations.

Comment: That's the point.

Comment: Funny that you'd have someone with the `xargs -0` GNUism, but not `find -exec {} +` (which GNU added long before the standard required it).

Comment: ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xargs.html if you have questions on that count.

Comment: i don't have any question. It's for fun only. :)